# SVN Relocate in Eclipse Issues

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, javahl

I'm trying to use the relocate function in Eclipse to switch the svn server my projects are looking at. I open the SVN Repositories view, right click the repository, choose relocate, type in the new url, and it just keeps spitting back:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Server does not support retrieving information about the root repository
```

I used to get the same error with the old server when I would check things out, but it would always pull up the directory listing regardless. If I add the new location in the SVN Repositories, I can browse it just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.0.0 in Eclipse 3.5.2. I also have

```
Subversion Client Adapter 1.5.3
Subversion JavaHL 1.5.7
Subversion Revision Graph 1.0.7
SVN Team Provider Core 1.4.8
SVNKit Client Adapter 1.5.6.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVN server we were using was a lil' out of date, so it wasn't supporting a request we were sending it. When Eclipse didn't get the reply it wanted, it failed and continued to go any further. I suppose the fix to this would be to upgrade your SVN server, but all we did was pointed DNS from the old server to the new server.